# Estimate contingency table entries from given marginal sums

Tags: contingency-tables, javascript

I have got a table with **known marginal sums**:

```
|  | | | 7|
|  | | | 7|
|  | | | 6|
|  | | | 6|
|  | | | 5|
|  | | | 4|
|  | | | 3|
+--+-+-+--+
|26|6|6|38|
```

I want to estimate the **best integer contingency table** to fulfil the row and column sums that minimises the error from the expected distribution.

1) I can calculate **estimates (float)**:

```
|4.79|1.11|1.11| 7|
|4.79|1.11|1.11| 7|
|4.11|0.95|0.95| 6|
|4.11|0.95|0.95| 6|
|3.42|0.79|0.79| 5|
|2.74|0.63|0.63| 4|
|2.05|0.47|0.47| 3|
+----+----+----+--+
|  26|   6|   6|38|
```

2) then round to the **nearest integer**:

```
| 5|1|1| 7|
| 5|1|1| 7|
| 4|1|1| 6|
| 4|1|1| 6|
| 3|1|1| 5|
| 3|1|1| 4|
| 2|0|0| 3|
+--+-+-+--+
|26|6|6|38|
```

This happens to work quite well but the row sums in the **last two rows don't match the target row sum**.

Is there an **algorithm** (javascript) to solve this generally?

Comment: How do you define the *expected distribution*?

Comment: @kjetil-b-halvorsen: The expected values would be the float estimates. The expected distribution of integers should be as close as possible to those float values.

Comment: Do you men, then, expected under independencia?

Comment: If you use the Chi-squared statistic to measure the error, this is an [integer quadratic program](https://www.google.com/search?q=integer+quadratic+program&oq=integer+quadratic+program).

Comment: The maximum entropy distribution, given fixed marginals, is the independence solution. So you could maximize entropy given the marginals, and under integer constraints. See https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177704014